# How to add a Note to an object using Open CTI

Tags: api, cti

I'm trying to add a Note to anything, really. Ultimately I'll need to add Notes to a Call History. I've tried adding a Note to a Contact, but no luck. Using saveLog() I can add an Account, a Task, and a Contact. In this example I'm trying to add a note to a test account:

```
sforce.interaction.saveLog('Note','ParentId=0018000001RHqlr&Title=ThisIsTheTitle&Body=CamelCaseTestText', saveLogCallback)
```

But simply nothing happens, no new Note, no errors. Any suggestions?